# What can pets be used for?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In pillars of eternity I've collected a bunch of pets on my travel, including a cat a wurm and some pigs.

What is the point of these pets? I can assign them to a slot and they follow me around but do I get any bonuses from them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pets do nothing for you or against you. They are just something neat to have follow you around / look at.
[Wiki says as much](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Pillars_of_Eternity_pets)